# Is it possible to drop the copies into a predefined folder as opposed to the root

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My company is using a google script to backup important files in google drive every day. The script makes an exact copy of the folder and subfolders and places to copy in the root of the drive. My question is: Is it possible to drop the copies into a predefined folder as opposed to the root.

```html
function start() {
  
  var sourceFolder = "original";
  var targetFolder = "backup";
  
  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);
 
  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
  
}
 
function copyFolder(source, target) {
 
  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();
  
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }
  
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.addFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the folder is predefined you have its folder id so you can use:

```
var predefined = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
```

then change target to:

```
var target = predefined.createFolder(targetFolder)
```

Comment: Using this method I end up with copies of the predefined target folder in the root each time the script is executed. Somehow not placing the files in the predefined folder but rather borrowing its name and adding the files.Any suggestions?

Comment: It works on my end, when the script is run multiple times new "backup" folders are created inside the predefined folder.  Also if you only have one "original" folder then you don't need to keep searching for it, you can use var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);

Comment: sorry I mean: var source = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);